# Graduate studies (phD & Masters) after a double degree

Tags: mathematics

I am planning on doing Bachelor of Computer Science - Bachelor of Mathematics at University of Wollongong, Australia. Do you think I will be able to do a phD in Mathematics by studying Mathematics as a double degree?

Comment: Are you asking whether you are able to get into a PhD program with a double major including math, or whether your studies will be sufficient?

Comment: Are you sure you will want to do a PHD in mathematics, after you actually graduate in 3 - 4 years from now? Isn't your question a bit premature?

Comment: @Compass , you got it right....Thats what im asking

Answer (score 3):

TLDR -- Yes.

Long answer -- A Ph.D. in Math is possible for a student who has double majored in Math and CS. A double major (at least in North America) consists of almost all the courses for both degrees. Taking some CS courses in undergrad is a good idea anyways for most math career paths.

With that said, Alexandros is right to point out that this is a bit premature. High school (and early undergraduate) math bears little if any resemblance to the math that a Ph.D. requires.